# How to Develop Multilingual Application with Angular 5?

Tags: angularjs, multilingual

Description :

I want to develop an application with some user ended forms with automated language convert option.

Example:

In my application, there is one form with different types of the field like FirstName, LastName etc.

Now On-screen user can see the same form twice, one with the English language and another with the Gujarati Language.

When User fills data into English form, that data automatically fill in Gujarati form. Like, suppose user write his firstname in English form than  In Gujarati form firstname field automatically fill with the Gujarati language.

Please refer below example image so anyone can get actual scenario.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: So, are you asking us how to translate a first name from English to Gujarati? If not, what exactly is your question? What is the concrete problem you faced when trying to do it?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes its kind of on-time translation of english to gujarati. 
Means User only fill english form , gujarati form automatically fill and display with values (may be user will change value if needed)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [ngx-translate](http://www.ngx-translate.com/)

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader rxjs --save
```

OR 
You can use [Angular Internationalization](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)

Hope this will helps